# Zoom is adding cookies to query parameters and refreshing the sign in page

Tags: python, selenium, automation, browser-automation, zoom-sdk

I am trying to automate a Zoom login on the browser using Selenium in Python.

The manual steps are as follows:

1. Visit https://www.zoom.us/signin
2. Enter the email and password.
3. Click in 'Sign in' button.

When I try to do the same steps using Selenium I am facing an issue on the step #1.

The `https://www.zoom.us/signin` page opens up. But then the page refreshes itself and the new URL contains two query parameters as follows: `https://www.zoom.us/signin?_x_zm_rtaid=<value>&_x_zm_rhtaid=<value>`. When the script then enters the correct email and password, the page throws a `HTTP 401 error`. This only happens during Selenium automation. If I do a manual login, `https://www.zoom.us/signin` page does not refresh itself, accepts the credentials and logs in successfully.

Here is what I tried. When the page refreshes and adds the query parameters and then gives the `HTTP 401` error, I intervened manually and removed the query parameters and loaded the `https://www.zoom.us/signin` page again. This time, it does not refresh itself, accepts the credentials entered manually, logs in successfully and my Python Selenium script continues executing successfully. So I thought that I could automate this manual removal of query parameters and reloading the page. However, I am not able to detect that the page has refreshed with query parameters in Selenium. I tried the following to detect that the page refreshed:

```py
wait.until(expected_conditions.url_contains('x_zm_rtaid'))
```

But the script keeps waiting for this condition before actually refreshing the page and then times out.

I would appreciate any help or direction in resolving this issue. Please let me know if any additional information is required from my side.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code, right after the libraries import, and it will work:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#THE FOLLOWING LINE IS THE SOLUTION OF THE PROBLEM
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
#in executable_path put the path to your chromedriver.exe
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://zoom.us")
```